# How do you access a method of object in Retrofit Response<List<Object>>

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I was able to accomplish the goal of calling a method from the object class in this instance:

```
@Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {
                ServerResponse resp = response.body();
                if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)){
                    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tv_message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    tv_message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tv_message.setText(resp.getMessage());
                }
            }
```

but in the problem instance, the response is a List of ServerResponse objects. so when I try to do the following:

```
@Override
                public void onResponse(Call<List<ServerResponse>> call, Response<List<ServerResponse>> response) {
                    List<ServerResponse> resp = response.body();
                    if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.FAILURE)){
                        tv_noResponses.setText(resp.getMessage());
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }else {
                        replyList = (ArrayList<ServerResponse>) response.body();
                        Collections.reverse(replyList);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mAdapter = new ReplyRecyclerAdapter(replyList, getActivity());
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    }
                }
```

the methods "getResult()" and "getMessage()" of course aren't available through the List interface, what do I have to do to make them available?

Comment: why are you making a list of ServerResponse ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getResult()` and `getMessage()` are methods in the `ServerResponse` class which are used to provide you with a result of your request as your preferences.

in your first request, you are expecting a **server response** to parse it into a ServerRespons object.but in the second request you are expecting a list of sth.

As I can Understand from your code. you are trying to retrieve a list of something (list of replays) to populate it inside the `RecyclerView`.

you don't need `getResult()` and `getMessage()` here. just make a

`List<YourModelOfRecyclerView>`. if sth went wrong with your request `onError()` will be called.

you can also modify your JSON response to add a custom server response with the list.and you will no longer need `ServerResponse` but a new Model that wraps your custom response and the list.